# Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm, inner-join, dql

`Ads` entity is described by geographic information: **Country> Region>County**. The `Ads` entity is only linked with `County`. Consequently, retrieving `Ads` by countries will require us joining entities twice.

My goal is counting the number of Ads for a given country. For that, I tried this DQL query but without success:

```
public function getMotorsAdsCountByCountry($slug){
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("m.id, COUNT(m.id) AS cnt")
            ->from("MinnAdsBundle:MotorsAds", "m")
            ->join("m.county","county")->addSelect("county")
            ->join("county.region","region")->addSelect("region")
            ->join("region.country","country")->addSelect("country")
            ->where("country.slug=:slug")
            ->setParameter(":slug", $slug);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

The error I got is:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT m.id,': Error: Cannot
> select entity through identification variables without choosing at
> least one root entity alias.

I have even seen a post regarding the same error in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878237/doctrine-cannot-select-entity-through-identification-variables-without-choosing) but without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("COUNT(m.id) AS cnt")
            ->from("MinnAdsBundle:MotorsAds", "m")
            ->join("m.county","county")
            ->join("county.region","region")
            ->join("region.country","country")
            ->where("country.slug=:slug")
            ->setParameter(":slug", $slug);
```

I have just remove the addSelect() in addition to the modification of the select().

Answer (score 2):

try changing

```
->select("m.id, COUNT(m.id) AS cnt")
```

to

```
->select("m, COUNT(m.id) AS cnt")
```

or change hydration to array

Comment: I tried both `->select("m, COUNT(m.id) AS cnt")` and `->select(array("m","COUNT(m.id) AS cnt"))` but without success! the error I get is: **500 Internal Server Error - NonUniqueResultException**

Answer (score 1):

this is known as Doctrine limitation you should first join with MotorAds Entity like this

```
from('MinnAdsBundle','mi')->leftJoin(MotorsAds::class,'m','WITH','mi.motorsAds = m');
```

then you can select form MotorsAds directly
refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46206970/9781506)

Comment: Moving to another EntityRepository didn't work. Changing `leftJoin` parameters as stated in this answer helped me.